# could not insert $username typed into a table

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Hi  I tried  inserting the  username that  they typed into the logattempt  table
but it does not recognize $username which i have already declared

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname = "hrms";
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

header("location: main.php");
} else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO logattempt (id, username, timest, failedatt)
VALUES ('John', '$username', 'john@example.com','asdfasdf')";
$conn->query($sql);
    header("location: index.php");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: print your $sql and then try that query in phpmyadmin console, see what happens

Comment: you are inserting "John" against id field, maybe thats producing the error. you can print the insert sql and try to run in the phpmyadmin. it will show exactly where is the error in your sql query.

Comment: @Michael Dela Cruz : id field auto increment or not?

Comment: Try removing first the redirect line (`header()`) and see if there are errors coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u set Id field as auto increment

change from

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO logattempt (id, username, timest, failedatt)
VALUES ('John', '$username', 'john@example.com','asdfasdf')";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO logattempt (id, username, timest, failedatt)
VALUES (null, '$username', 'john@example.com','asdfasdf')";
```